# Macos opens Instruments when I press "Command" + "~"

Tags: google-chrome, mission-control

The default combination to switch between windows of the current app in macOS is <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>`</kbd>. Unfortunately when I have opened Chrome and I want to switch between its windows, <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>`</kbd> opens Instruments.

If I switch windows in the opposite direction with <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> <kbd>`</kbd>  - everything works fine.

Is there a way to disable Chrome behavior so switching windows would work in it as well?

Comment: @user3439894 yes, I can change the default shortcut in keyboard settings so it won't overlap with chrome's one. But is it possible to remove this behavior of ⌘ + ` in chrome?

Comment: I edited the question, I meant the ` character. It's just they are on the same key. Nope I didn't set any additional shortcuts, at least I don't remember it. How can I check if it's set somewhere?

Comment: Cmd-` (backtick)  is supposed to default to "Move focus to next Window."  If you're seeing "Instruments" something's been modified.  What do you see in Keyboard shortcuts in System Preferences?

Comment: @user3439894 thank you, that's it. I have Activity Monitor at Sevices -> development in the keyboard settings. I was looking for it in Keyboard settings before.  If you post your it as an answer I will accept it . https://api.pychat.org/photo/EWDbKQoM_Sun_Nov_08_2020.png I don't remember editing this shorcut myself. I'm almost sure that it has been set itself after I installed something like XCode

Comment: @deathangel908, I have **Xcode** installed too, and by default is does not assigned a _keyboard shortcut_ to **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** > **Development** > **Activity Monitor**, but somehow it got set on your system. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately when I have opened Chrome and I want to switch between its windows, **⌘`** opens Instruments.

As **Instruments** is a part of **Xcode**, not **Google Chrome**, check the **Chrome** > **Services** menu for a *service* assigned: **⌘`**

You can change it in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**